# Disable long touch context menu on dynamic button in iOS in JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery

I'm developing an web app in Jquery Mobile for mobile devices and I want to disable long press behavior on iOS devices.
I use CSS:

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none !important;
-webkit-user-select: none !important;
-khtml-user-select: none !important;
-ms-user-select: none !important;
-moz-user-select: none !important;
-user-select: none !important;
```

on elements (for example buttons) but if I create buttons dynamically, then this CSS style doesn't work properly and I got still long press context menu (copy, open...) on iOS. On other devices work fine. What can I do with that ?
thanks

Comment: iOS should honour -webkit-touch-callout and -webkit-user-select. Perhaps the problem is somewhere else. Can you show a minimal sample (http://sscce.org/) showing the problem?

Comment: Hi...I already solved this problem. There wasn't problem with css style after all. The problem was in TAG <a>. I used <button> instead and it works fine. :)

Comment: Well, iOS should honour -webkit-touch-callout and -webkit-user-select for <a> as well..